# How to scrape those country names?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape all the players' ratings from this [website](https://www.ea.com/games/fifa/fifa-23/womens-ratings)

My code generated a table which has numbers instead of names in the 'nationality' column. I couldn't find a way to decipher this.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

url = 'https://ratings-api.ea.com/v2/entities/fifa-23-womens-rating?sort=ranking%3AASC&limit=1200'
r = requests.get(url)
json_data = json.loads(r.text)
data_docs = json_data['docs']

FIFA23_rating = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_docs)
```

Dataset after cleaning:

```
    full_name   nationality birthyear   position    height  weight  overall_rating  pac
0   Alexia Putellas Segura  45  1994    CM  173 67  92  80
1   Sam Kerr    195 1993    ST  168 66  91  87
2   Wendie Renard   18  1990    CB  187 70  91  67
3   Ada Hegerberg   36  1995    ST  176 68  91  85
4   Marie Katoto    18  1998    ST  177 66  90  88
```

Any suggestion on how to get those country names?

Comment: Could you find nationality codes for ex; 1 is japan 2 is Korea etc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ratings api doesn't return the country name in the api response. Also, I've checked that they don't annotate by ISO codes either.

What you can simply do is collect all the unique codes that you receive for nationality field and build your own annotation dict using the flag images.

They are stored in here like following:
[https://media.contentapi.ea.com/content/dam/ea/fifa/fifa-21/ratings-collective/f20assets/country-flags/**{nationality}.png*](https://media.contentapi.ea.com/content/dam/ea/fifa/fifa-21/ratings-collective/f20assets/country-flags/**%7Bnationality%7D.png*)*

Shortest way for building your annotator could be filtering the result by unique nationality codes:
You can simply use the `&filter=nationality%3A({nationality})` at the end of the api url to filter out players by nationality and then check if you can extract by the team names or so. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

For example, [here](https://ratings-api.ea.com/v2/entities/fifa-23-womens-rating?sort=ranking%3AASC&limit=1200&filter=nationality%3A(52)) you'll find all the `Argentina Women` in the `teamname` field by appending `&filter=nationality%3A(52)` at the end of the url.

To be honest, you need to decode their country code for the `nationality` field either way. I gave you two ideas you can brainstorm your own idea as well. :) Good luck.